# Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, indexing, undefined, http-referer

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

$http_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

i used this from tutorial.and it looks okay

also code is calling it from including file

what should i change?

**i added print_r($_SERVER); and now page gives me this**

```
 Array ([UNIQUE_ID] => UoSxWa56310AAAwUckIAAAAA
        [HTTP_HOST] => movafaghha.com
        [HTTP_COOKIE] => __utma=210711305.58608218.1372977010.1372977010.1372977010.1; __utmz=210711305.1372977010.1.1.utmcsr=who.is|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/whois/movafaghha.com; PHPSESSID=83eb0e2ae7ebe4b6c2eeb071d9f5de71
        [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 109.109.41.81
        [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST] => movafaghha.com
        [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER] => movafaghha.com
        [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 109.109.41.81
        [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close 
        [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0 
        [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
        [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.48 Safari/537.36 
        [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6 
        [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
        [SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>
        [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache 
        [SERVER_NAME] => movafaghha.com 
        [SERVER_ADDR] => 174.122.223.93 
        [SERVER_PORT] => 80 
        [REMOTE_ADDR] => 109.109.41.81 
        [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/memarest/public_html/movafaghha.com 
        [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@movafaghha.memarestan.com 
        [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/memarest/public_html/movafaghha.com/tutorials/login200/register.php 
        [REMOTE_PORT] => 49737 
        [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 
        [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0 
        [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET 
        [QUERY_STRING] => 
        [REQUEST_URI] => /tutorials/login200/register.php 
        [SCRIPT_NAME] => /tutorials/login200/register.php 
        [PHP_SELF] => /tutorials/login200/register.php 
        [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1384427865.54 
        [REQUEST_TIME] => 1384427865 
        [argv] => Array ( ) 
        [argc] => 0 
    )
```

edited the code but still unable to echo all fiedds are required

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'core.inc.php';






if(!loggedIn()) {

//check mikunim ke tamame field ha dar form vojod darand va set shudan

if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_POST['password_again'])&&isset($_POST['firstname'])&&isset($_POST['surename'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_again = $_POST['password_again'];
    $firtsname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surename = $_POST['surename'];



    //HALA CHECK MIKUNIM KHALI HASTAND YA NA

    if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($password_again)&&!empty($firstname)&&!empty($surename)){
        echo 'ok' ;

    } else {

        echo ' All fields are required';

    }

}




?>

<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username:<br> <input type="text" name="username"><br> <br>
Password:<br> <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
Password again:<br> <input type="password" name="password_again"><br><br>
Firstname:<br> <input type="text" name="firstname"><br><br>
Surname:<br> <input type="text" name="surename"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="register">



</form>

<?php

} elseif (loggedIn()) {

    echo 'you \'re already logged in';
    }

?>
```

now after adding

> "e"

page says "all fields are required"

but even when  fill all fields message do not change

Comment: you should test for this variable existence. If you're not coming from another page but typed the link to the page directly in address bar, there won't be any referer...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is not guaranteed to be sent by the client:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

In your case it's clearly *not* being sent, so really all you can do is

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  //do what you need to do here if it's set    
   }
else
{
   //it was not sent, perform your default actions here
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think original question might have asked to block some spam website (at least in my case). In the above solution, action will be performed in all the cases. Here is what I did:                            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'www.spamwebsite.com') {//action}.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {$THE_REFER=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}
```

Comment: The `isset` method returns a boolean. Your `$THE_REFER` variable will be `"true"` or `"false"`, not the actual value of the referer header.

Comment: @JeffKilbride Thank you for your comment. This post is for 2 years ago... i don't know why i have sent this illogical post! i have shocked! I have edited it. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index means the array key is not set, do a:

```
var_dump($_POST); die();
```

before the line that throws the error and see that you're trying to get an array key that does not exist.

Answer (score -2):

The Correct way to reffer is

```
$my_referer = isset($_POST['referer']) ? trim($_POST['referer']) : (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) : false);
```