# Wordpress Plugin Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this error when trying t activate my plugin:

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in
>   /home/gateway/domains/gateway.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/includes/admin/admin.php
>   on line 48

On this line is this block:

```
//change upload directory
public function user_upload_files_dir($upload) {
    //check if this a user-edit page
    $current_page = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $current_page_tmp = explode("?", $current_page);
    $current_page = $current_page_tmp[0];
    if ($current_page != "user-edit.php")
        return $upload;
```

I have done some homework but I can't understand if either my code is wrong, or it is somehow my browser refusing to give the user agent?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976189/notice-undefined-index-http-referer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP documentation:

> *'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.*

In your case it's clearly not being sent, so really all you can do is to check:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  //do what you need to do    
   }
else
{
   //it was not sent, default action
}
```