# Get request page name or url when doing a redirection

Tags: php

How to get the request page name or uri from which the source page is loaded.

### Explanation below:

index.php

```
<?php
  header('Location:target.php');
?>
```

target.php

```
<?php
  // How to check here if the redirection has happened from index.php
?>
```

Comment: Tried `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the previous url using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662110/how-to-get-the-previous-url-using-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the code below

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

but to make sure you can get really the exact origin of your page you can store the current url to a session before doing a redirection and read it to the next page.

in the origin page

```
$_SESSION['origin'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

then in next page

```
echo $_SESSION['origin'];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] but it can't be trusted. Some browsers will have the correct value other will have null value.

Here is what php manual says about it:

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.**

In short, I don't think you can get a reliable solution for what you want.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response. It was helpful. But i think the solution to store it in database gives my question a solution. Appreciate your help.