# redirect page to main link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way I can protect a page from being accessed unless it's from a particular referral URL? ie. if someone is on Page A and clicks a link to go to Page B, they would access it fine but if a person from anywhere else tries to access Page B, they get an error or possibly just redirected to Page A.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662110/how-to-get-the-previous-url-using-php

Comment: hmm... create a query that updates if a page is being used.

Comment: laugh at any ones that says use the referrer and go down the sessions road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this *properly*

page a:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['accssed_a']='yes';
//rest of page
```

page b:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['accssed_a']!='yes'){
header('Location: http://example.com/a.php');
exit();
}
//rest of page
```

Comment: Hi, Dagon, Thanks for the help, but the code not working on my end,page B still not redirecting to Page A when i first load it.

Comment: i forgot the exit(), both pages are *.php and access through a server ?

Comment: Drago, thank u so much for helping. Its perfectly working now.

Comment: Nice, I'll be sure to remember this.