# How to detect URL from user came in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to detect URL from user came in Codeigniter?

For example, I am at page: **/contact/**, after click the link with url **/news/** at controller `news` I must detect the previous URL **/contact/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably grab the referring page using the PHP `$_SERVER` array.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Specifically: `HTTP_REFERER`

You may need to parse the string to get the part that you need.

Comment: Some browsers may omit this field (private browsing mode, etc.), so don't forget to check for its existence: `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {...}`

Comment: **Note :** anybody can spoof it at anytime regardless of whether they clicked on a link or they simply don't sent it at all to begin with.
[refrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662110/how-to-get-the-previous-url-using-php)