# fetching url of the page from where php script is triggered

Tags: php, server

i have a php script named as "abc.com/autologin.php". This autologin.php is hyperlinked to a button on another web portal def.com. so when a user on def.com click the button he visit abc.com/autologin.php.

So in autologin.php i want to fetch the url of the page where that button is clicked. Url is dynamic as it contains parameters different for different users.

Comment: I believe this is the answer you searching for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662120/8807094

Comment: @Kussensloop It's not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since URL cannot be fetched from the server side, it's better to use client side to get the URL. Also, it's slightly unreliable to rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. As always the request goes to the same PHP file, it's better to add a hidden input field which explicitly says from which URL, the request is originating.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fromPage" value="feedbackForm" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="https://www.example.com/feedback.html" />
```

And then capture them in your `REQUEST` data using:

```
$_REQUEST["fromPage"]
$_REQUEST["url"]
```

Comment: can you just elaborate please. you mean to say i have add input field to the autologin.php . how to fetch the dynamic url.

Comment: @prem I just told you can capture them in your `REQUEST` data using:

    `$_REQUEST["fromPage"]` and 
    `$_REQUEST["url"]`. Do you know PHP or not?

Comment: my mistake i didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER` global variable to find referrer details.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the referrer page's URL if there exists any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` for more info http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php