# Are there any events or hooks available for shop change?

Tags: shopware

Are there any events or hooks available to detect the shop change form frontend (shop change dropdown in the header.)?

How we can check the customer changed the shop in frond-end? (I what to do some function after the shop change in my plugin).

Comment: You can check in your frontend subscriber if the `.language--form` was sent, e.g. like `$request->getPost('__shop') !== null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the change manually by checking the previous url to the current url with PHP.

Here is an entry on how to get the previous URL: [How to get the previous url using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662110/how-to-get-the-previous-url-using-php)

You can hook any Shopware Event which is always fired in Shopware. You could use the Event "Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend" and extend it.

Greetings Patrick