# if (!isset($_GET ['reload'])) of a specific link

Tags: php, function

I tried to use this function to refresh the page as soon as I entered the site.

```php
if (!isset($_GET ['reload'])) { 
    header("Refresh:0 url=https://luxurybites.it/?reload=true");
}
```

But my aim is to refreshare the page only by accessing the site via a specific link
For example, by entering through the link "www.urlspecific.it" The page is refreshed.
Can you help me or direct me in the right way please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous url using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662110/how-to-get-the-previous-url-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the intention is to redirect to a URL if a condition is met. The location header redirects ...

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
    header('Location: https://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: can you explain why?